# How to declare a global variable from a form input and api call using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a basic login page for my react application.  The user submits a form to login and if the username and password match the database, then it sets an object equal to all the variables associated with that username and password.  I would like to be able to access this object in all other pages of the application by making it a global variable but I can't quite figure out how.

```
doSubmit = async () => {
    const { userList, userLoggedIn, data } = this.state;

    for (let x in this.state.userList) {
      if (
        data.email === userList[x].email &&
        data.password === userList[x].password
      ) {
        userLoggedIn.email = userList[x].email;
        userLoggedIn.password = userList[x].password;
        userLoggedIn.id = userList[x].user_id;
      }
    }
  };
```

This function happens when the user presses submit. Data is what the user input into the login form.  UserList is an array retrieved from the database API that contains all the objects of usernames and passwords.  UserLoggedIn is the object that I would like to be able to access globally for the rest of my application.  I need to get the id of the user logged in to make other API calls on other pages.  Thank you for any help, sorry if this doesn't really make sense honestly I am kinda lost.  I know using token authentication might be a possible solution but due to certain circumstances that is not an option here.

Comment: _UserList is an array retrieved from the database API that contains all the objects of usernames and passwords._ Handling sensitive user data (credentials) on client is very bad idea.

Comment: @hindmost yea I agree 100% in usual setting but with this application, we are giving the users their premade username and password so it is not as sensitive.  I think that makes this okay? I'm still learning

Comment: Anyway, it'd be better to move all that searching logic to server.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store it in a global variable.

Store it in the state of the top-level component, and then pass it down to where it is needed through props.

Define your `doSubmit` method on that top-level component and pass it down to the login form.

To simplify passing it down, use the new [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) feature.